# Executable jar file became jar file only?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, build, executable-jar

I made a project and build it to a executable jar file. My problem is its an executable jar file in my computer but when I transfer it to another computer it became a jar file only. What is the problem here? I'm using netbeans 8.0.2

Comment: Missing resources? Misconfigured system settings?

Comment: @MadProgrammer what do you mean?

Comment: You may be addressing resources which are only accessible from your machine, which is causing the Jar to fail or Java may be misconfigured and isn't capable of running the Jar or the `.jar` isn't associated with Java

Comment: @MadProgrammer what are thing that need to be able to run jar file?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Do you mean it's missing executable permissions?

Comment: It cannot "become" not executable JAR. The only difference between executable JAR and non-executable JAR is in its contents, and the contents won't change when you move them to another computer. As others note, what can happen is your executable JAR not getting executed - which should be the problem of dependencies and/or system configuration. How are you running it? If nothing else, you can run it from command line (or run prompt) using `java -jar jarname.jar` assuming your Java works and your file has no classpath dependencies.

Comment: You all depended libraries/jars (typically found in the `dist/lib` of the netbeans project); any external resources you might be reliant on (images/files)

Comment: Is Java installed on the target machine? Jar cannot be executed without JRE.

Comment: Maybe on the target machine is a Java JRE installed with a lower version than the JAR was build with.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have java installed on the second computer, or the  installation is not default, so the "jar" extension is not registered?

try in console:

```
 java -version

 #if you have java, you can start your jar from command line:

 java -jar youJarName.jar
```